# How to map a Map into another Map using Java Stream?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, stream, java-stream

I'm learning Java with Stream and I have this `Map<String, List<Customer>> map1` and I want to map it into this `Map<String, List<CustomerObj>> map2`. How can I do this especially using Java Stream? Any feedback will be apreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can `stream` the entries of `map1` and collect with `Collectors.toMap`, using key mapper `Map.Entry::getKey`. For the value mapper you can get the entry value list, then `stream` and map from `Customer` to `CustomerObj`, and finally collect to `List`.

Here's and example using `Integer` instead of `Customer` and `String` instead of `CustomerObj`:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map1 = Map.of(
        "A", List.of(1, 2), 
        "B", List.of(3, 4), 
        "C", List.of(5, 6));
    
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = map1.entrySet().stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                        .map(String::valueOf).toList()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like so:

```java
Customer c1 = new Customer("İsmail", "Y.");
Customer c2 = new Customer("Elvis", "?.");
        
Map<String, List<Customer>> customerList = new HashMap<>();
customerList.put("U1", Arrays.asList(c1));
customerList.put("U2", Arrays.asList(c1, c2));
        
Map<String, List<CustomerObj>> customerObjList = customerList
        .entrySet().stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                        entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                                .map(CustomerObj::new)
                                // or .map(c -> new CustomerObj(c))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                )
        );
    }
```

```java
private static class Customer {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}

private static class CustomerObj {

    private String fullName;

    public CustomerObj(Customer customer) {
        this.fullName = String.join(" ",
                customer.getFirstName(), customer.getLastName()
        );
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
}
```

*@Oboe's answer works in `Java 16+` and this answer is similar to your models and easier to understand.*